# Making 'circles' on a lattice/ Making distinct fractions from partitions of a number

Tags: discrete-geometry, nt.number-theory, convex-polytopes

#### First formulation: discrete geometry

Pick your favourite 2D square lattice (I'm sure we all have one...) and try to place n points 'in a circle' (that is: in general position [no 3 should be colinear] and forming the vertices of a convex polygon). Easy-peasy (assuming your favourite lattice is infinite- I know mine is). But now make your lattice smaller- finite even- say, $K \times K$- can you still do it? What is K is smaller? Bigger? Clearly the answer depends on n, so we ask:

> What is the smallest $K=K(n)$ such that this can be done?

#### Motivation?

This little problem- way out of my comfort zone in terms of field- was sort of inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27618/upper-bound-for-the-number-of-subsets-of-n-points-which-exhaust-their-convex-hull). It initially looked like an interesting problem but, sadly, turned out to be rather trivial- putting points in a circle spelled trouble, it seemed, and I idly suggested a finite lattice to stop it happening- idle suggestion turned to idle speculation and I began to wonder how small the lattice had to be to stop the circle forming- beyond that, intrigue is the only reason why I am pursuing it.

So far my progress has been scant, but I have found a rather interesting reformulation: by focusing on the most densely populated 'quadrant' of the lattice and observing that the gradients of the edges within it must all differ. Modulo some suitable considerations of n mod 4 we can get-

#### Reformulation: number theory

> Given $\hat{n}$ what is the smallest $\hat{K}$ such that we may find $\hat{n}$ distinct fractions $\frac{p_1}{q_1},....\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ with $\Sigma_i q_i \leq \Sigma_i p_i = \hat{K}$?

Here $\hat{n}$ would be the number of points in the quadrant $\hat{K} \times \hat{K}$ the smallest size of that quadrant.

If we set $\hat{n}=\lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil$, assume $\hat{K}=\frac{K}{2}$ and let the $p_i$, $q_i$ be the first $\hat{n}$ natural numbers we get a [really crappy] upper bound of $K \leq \lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil (\lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil +1)$- this fails to be sharp by the time n=5 for obvious reasons- 1) There has been no real consideration of the mod 4 behaviour and 2) By no means is this the most efficient way to make differing fractions.

Fixing 1) seems pretty easy (we can look at 2 different quadrants), but I didn't want to clog up the question with numerics when 2) is the real toughie. As mentioned above, I am neither a discrete geometer nor a number theorist, so this may unwind to be as trivial as the question that inspired it- still, to me it seems intriguing- and I am sufficiently invested to be hankering for an answer.

**Edit:** Gjergji's answer seems to be pretty great as a problem posed for polytopes, but I haven't accepted it yet because I am curious- can the number theory formulation do better? Is there a sharper result in that context?

Answer (score 5):

I believe your question (and many other variations) are answered [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/aw6wx84015357770/). Also see [this](http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/psurveyAMS.pdf) survey by I. Barany about extremal problems for convex lattice polytopes.

Actually the problem for the convex polygon inside the square was considered earlier than that. See [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WHS-4D0YB4K-9&_user=1010281&_coverDate=02%2F28%2F1995&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050264&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=1010281&md5=aeb538fb3d97eae79dfddcc646bba7f3) for an article that seems to be written more in the lines of your question. The result is that
$$K(n)\sim 2\pi \left(\frac{n}{12}\right)^{2/3}.$$

Comment: The first one seems more asymptotic than my query, the second though does seem to cover it... Although, and maybe I'm being a bit thick here, I can't seem to get his bound for the width of a lattice 10-gon: he says "The reader will have no diffculty finding a convex lattice polygon with n vertices having lattice width exactly  $\lciel n/2 \rceil- 1$". I am having difficulty. Is it possible he saw n=1-8 attaining his lower bound and assumed the rest? I am probably just being a pillock- can you fit a convex 10-gon in a lattice width of 4?  

Comment: I mean, you can do it easily if you don't need general position- but he seems to use g.p. in his definition of convex "since every lattice line contains at most 2 vertices of P...".

Comment: Oh, in that case I believe he is only considering width in one direction, which shouldn't be of much interest to you, since you are considering points in convex position in a confined area (square). I was referring to the section "maximal polytopes in K", being of interest, but I figured the new article I added above is a much better reference.

Comment: +1 I came here to point to Barany's work on exactly this problem (I saw him speak on it at IPAM last fall) but I see you've already done so.

Comment: Bah... that last result looks like the business but I can't see it without forking out $30. Damn those journal subscription fees... it really bugs me when I don't get to see the solution- it's like watching half of a movie- +1 though. Ps. I think your index might be upside-down- my bound isn't great- but it's nowhere near as bad as o(n^2) vs o(n^2/3) !

Comment: PPs. Hey, does this mean i have just proved something in number theory?!

Comment: The links to the articles at `springerlink.com` and `sciencedirect.com` are broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible…

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking about prime denominators: you should be able to take K to be n to the power 2/3, up to some logarithmic stuff. This is just greedily taking a bunch of primes in some interval. There is a little to be gained by using the whole Farey series.

[The condition on the numerators looks slightly troublesome. Just taking the p/q where q is fixed and p coprime to q is going to have the sum of p's around half the sums of q's, on average (or a bit less ...). But this can be worked round: take the "second half" of the p/q with p at least q/2, with the 1 + p/q for the "first half" where p is less than q/2.]